# Can we record audio in PC (not Android) using wireless headsets(inbuilt mic)?

Tags: audio, compatibility, audio-recording, wireless-headset

I would like to know whether we can record audio in PC (again, not Android) using wireless headsets(inbuilt mic) which use bluetooth for connectivity. I am casting doubt because I read that they can be used only for calls not for audio recording (not talking about call recording because it's confusing). Also, I would like to know the quality difference between the audio recorded in wired one vs wireless one.

Edit:- This is the link from Quora where the original question was asked and it confused me(see the comment in answer). https://www.quora.com/Can-wireless-bluetooth-headset-work-as-a-microphone-for-audio-recording-If-yes-then-which-ones

Comment: Your question is too broad and lacks detail. You are asking too many questions at once. Perhaps you should ask whether and how you can record audio from a bluetooth headset under a particular operating system. I assume you haven't bought the headset yet, and you don't know if it will work?

Comment: @slhck I have edited the question now. I know that we can record audio through a wired headset, with its mic like physical straw type angled cable, but I have read that we can't record audio through wireless headset(inbuilt mic) it can only be used for calling purpose. So my question is that can we record audio in pc via inbuilt mic of wireless headset , not through inbuilt one of PC?

Comment: "I have read that we can't record audio through wireless headset" – where? Do you have a link? There's nothing that prevents this, really.

Comment: @slhck You should see my edited question where the quora link is given. See comment to the answer of that question. Again, I hadn't purchased the wireless headset so just wanted to clarify the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop/PC can connect with the headphones via bluetooth (Whether it has embedded bluetooth or the headphones have a dedicated bluetooth usb bundle), the PC will not even "know" that the headphones are wireless.
In other words, if you successfully connect the headphones with the computer, you are ok.

Comment: I want to know that whether the audio will be recorded via inbuilt mic of PC or through inbuilt mic of wireless headset since PC will get confused! Usually, we test external mic by connecting headset with PC and then speaking in external mic but from some distance. If audio is clear, it's the signal that external mic is used successfully, but I want to know whether that test will be successful in wireless headset- that's the technical aspect of my question.

Comment: What prevents you from doing the same test with a wireless mic? You can even go farther away with a Bluetooth mic to make sure it picks up the signal from there and not the built-in mic.

Comment: @slhck As I said, I haven't yet bought it so just wanted to have clarity.

Comment: @nikhil your recording software should let you choose which Mic you want it to use.

Comment: @kicken Ok, I got it.

Comment: Or right click on the volume icon and choose *Open Sound Settings* then choose input device. You can also right-click and choose *Sounds* and select the *Recording* tab to see all devices